# Lock cell in google sheets after data has been entered

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to develop a google sheet sign in for students to indicate when they arrive and when they are leaving.  This will be available to other students to access via a school laptop in the main office.  I want to lock the student name once it has been typed in.  I have been searching for "how to lock a cell once data has been entered".  My reasoning is to inhibit other students from altering a student's information.  However, my script is not working.  Any suggestions?

```js
function onEdit(e) { 
 var active =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet Name").getActiveCell();
 active.protect().removeEditor("other editors emails");
 active.setNote("Locked");
  }
```

Comment: As an aside, you might be better served by using Google Forms to collect responses and integrating it with a private Google Sheets workbook that's only accessible to staff. If you're more comfortable with Excel formulas, I'd definitely recommend this route; it avoids the editability situation without requiring Google Apps Script. You could use some creative `vlookup` calls to display the most recent arrival and departure of each student by their unique identifier (or their name, if you don't have UIDs). You can link a form to an existing spreadsheet in one click via the Tools menu.